# Extend class methods in PHP

Tags: php, object, methods, extend

I am doing a custom CMS and I have built my base content class like this:

```
class Content
{
  public $title;
  public $description;
  public $id;

  static function save()
  {
    $q = "[INSERT THE DATA TO BASE CONTENT TABLE]";
  }
}

class Image extends Content
{
  public $location;
  public $thumbnail;

  public function save()
  {
     // I wanted to do a Content::save() here if I 
     //  declare Contents::save() as static
     $q = "[INSERT THE DATA TO THE IMAGE TABLE]";
  }
}
```

My problem is this I know that static function cannot use `$this` but I know that `Content::save()` needs to use it.

I want `Image::save()` to call `Content::save()` but I wanted them to be both named `save()` and be declared `public` and not `static` because I need `$this`.

Will the only solution be renaming `Content::save()` so I can use it within `Image::save()`?

Or is there a way of extending methods?

Comment: `Content::save` is not declared static in your sample. Are you sure you have posted everything right?

Comment: PHP supports calling something static, eventhough its not defined as static. As long as you dont use $this, all is fine.

Comment: What is your actual question btw? Should Image call Content's save?

Comment: @JOHN, the function as posted before is how I wanted it to look like, that is why I inserted a comment at `Image::save()`: _if I declare Contents::save() as static_

Comment: @TJHeuvel: I am sorry if I am not able to articulate what I want to do well, yes I want `Image::save()` to call `Content::save()` but I wanted both to be called `save()`. I want both to be `public` and not `static` because I need `$this`. Is that possible?

Comment: Public properties, static methods... You are doing it wrong. It will be useful to you to read books about good practices in programming. [This one](http://www.amazon.com/Objects-Patterns-Practice-Matt-Zandstra/dp/1590599098), as variant.

Comment: @OZ_: the original post had a public method. It was edited due to JOHN's comment

Comment: @Rolando Cruz, public properties are much worse :) It's not just to be critic, I want to give useful advice.

Comment: No.. I really liked that you commented on my design. Too bad I cannot afford such books that's why I can only learn when somebody criticizes my code.

Comment: well... [you know](http://www.4shared.com/document/bwAKsQfG/PHP_Objects_Patterns_and_Pract.html) :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [parent](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php) to get the upper class. Even though in the following sample you call it using `parent::Save`, you can still use `$this` in the parent class.

```
<?php

class A
{
    public function save()
    {
        echo "A save";
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function save()
    {
        echo "B save";
        parent::save();
    }
}
$b = new B();
$b->save();
?>
```

Comment: That looks just right. Thanks! Waiting for 1 minute to accept. Why do stackoverflow have this time restriction on accepting answers anyway?